# FirebaseAuth: How to change phone number already linked to a provider?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am working on a Flutter app which uses Firebase Authentication. I have used multiple providers and phone verification for the registration process.

I want to give an option to the user to change the phone number linked to their email ID. But for that, I need to verify the number again. And I'm having trouble doing that.

I am using `unlinkFromProvider` function and then linking it again using `linkWithCredential`.
Here is the code for that.

```
FirebaseUser _firebaseUser = await _auth.currentUser();
var credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
  smsCode: smsCode,
  verificationId: verificationId,
);
await _firebaseUser.unlinkFromProvider(_firebaseUser.providerId);
result = await _firebaseUser.linkWithCredential(credential);
```

But on doing this, I am getting this error

> ERROR_NO_SUCH_PROVIDER: User was not linked to an account with the given provider.

I believe it means that the provider ID might be wrong.

How can I get the correct provider ID? Am I doing it completely wrong?

If yes, what is the right way to do this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for helping and I will mark the answer that helped me, it's just that because of some priority I shifted to other stuff so I haven't got much time for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not unlink the provider to re-verify the user's phone number. Instead you should [reauthenticate the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#reauthenticate(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)) with the reverification credentials.

After that, you can then call [`updatePhoneNumber` to update the number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#public-taskvoid-updatephonenumber-phoneauthcredential-credential).

Comment: Hey Frank, I am facing one issue here, the number is getting updated in firebase without the phone verification process. If I do the verification process before changing the number then I get an error saying that the provider is already linked, is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't know what's happening there. It'd be good if you show (here or in a new question) the [minimal code that reproduces thats problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate inside the `providerData` list to get the correct `providerId`:

```
      FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      user.providerData.forEach((element) {
        element.providerId;
      });
```

`_firebaseUser.providerId` is most probably returning `firebase`, when you iterate inside the providerData, you will then get the providerid `phone`, and then you can unlink.

Comment: Thank you Peter for helping, although I used the other method to solve the problem but thanks for sharing your knowledge!